# Observables vs Tasks - preferred implementation?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I simply want to retrieve data asynchronously, and after retrieving the data, show it in the UI (Winforms).

Using .net 4.0, there are 2 ways that I can implement this (I know there are more, but I am using these two):

```
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RetrieveData());
    task.ContinueWith(x => SetDataInUi(x.Result), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

OR

```
var obs = Observable.Start(() => RetrieveData());
obs.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(x => SetDataInUi(x));
```

To the best of my understanding, these will both do the same thing. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: Might be wrong, but I think you can replace `() => RetrieveData()` with just `RetrieveData`. And similarly replace `x => SetDataInUi(x)` with just `SetDataInUi`.

Comment: @Domenic - It is possible, but then I have to explicitly call StartNew<returnType>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to request data from somewhere and print it to screen, I would prefer the first solution.

The second one works too, but RX was designed to help you with data flows. And we all agree it's not cool to use a complex solution when you can use a simple one :)

Comment: The Rx version is shorter, how is it more complex?

Comment: The code he writes is shorter, but the mechanism RX uses if for more complex cases than this one. It's a matter of using the simple thing to the simple problem.

Comment: Having room to grow isn't bad. What if he wanted this fetch to be triggered from a user interaction now? No reason not to start with Observables in the case that he eventually wants to use it in a more complex way. Sometimes maintainability is more important and certainly the Rx is more immediately readable and composable. I see that Observables *can* be used to do more complex things, but that doesn't make them complex by themselves. I find this choice to be a matter of taste more than anything else.

Comment: I disagree. Rx is more expressive (partly due to the use of LINQ expressions). Rx is also able to unify all of the async and event programming models in .NET into a single model. It's worth using just for that.

Comment: If it's a simple task that I want to be run on a separate thread, I'll use a task. If I'm feeling lazy I might just use a background worker! If I'm funnelling data around I'll use Rx as its simple to filter and subscribe at multiple points. Having said that, some of my colleagues just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there shouldn't be a major difference between those two implementations.

Those are different APIs that provide different models for describing similar operations.

The `Task` API provides a way of avoiding using threads directly, and instead work with individual tasks you want to perform.

The `Reactive` API provides a way of funneling data between different operations in an efficient manner.

In this case your problem lies in both realms. You are working with a small task that is not worth explicit threads, and you are directing the data flow with your result. However the former definition is a more complete describer, so it is probably the solution you should use.

Does any of your existing code use either solution? Matching what you do elsewhere helps improve readability, and overrides this consideration.

Also note that sometimes when comparing APIs you have to consider dependencies, not in this case, but it is good to keep in mind in general.

Comment: In this case, I believe .Net Framework won't be a problem. Since the Task API was introduced in .Net 4

Comment: @rodrigovedovato: I thought it was 3.5, I will rephrase, I was trying to keep it abstract but relevant, and kind of failed.